# REGEX catch function name even with recursively use

Tags: php, python, regex, function

I am trying to catch the name of functions of a PHP code source using regex in Python, these are example of catched lines presented in the following:

```
perf_mmap__read_init(map, true, &start, &end);
while ((event = perf_mmap__read_event(map, true, &start, end)) != NULL) {
if (perf_mmap__read_init(md, opts->overwrite, &start, &end) < 0)
```

There recursively problem is when we have a call of function in the parameters itself. My goal is to capt all function names, even those that we call in the parameter of function and so on.

This is an example of the cited problem:

```
set_pmd(pmd, pfn_pmd(__phys_to_pfn(phys), sect_prot));
```

This is my try, I used this simple regex, but I can't attend the recursive usage :

`Regex: (\w+)\(.*`

Comment: I left you a comment in your previous question. Did you check it?

Comment: yes I did, When I run it in all the test cases, it gives me thousand of mismatches. I will try to find the best expression using the website you sent me. Then I will share result here. Thank you for your previous response

Comment: I am guessing you do have multiple (more than two) functions strings in your test cases, right?

Comment: Actually, it is a diff result big file. I have to treat the maximum of test cases that could happens

Comment: I am working on that here, but I couldn't reach the recursive calls of functions

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/n7B3ox/2

Comment: Any help to resolve recursive call ?

Comment: ^[-(?!--)|\+(?!\+\+)].*?([a-zA-Z_\d]+)\(.*\).*$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found finally that Regex :

`([\w]+)(?=\()`

That Regex helped me to catch all the function names even with the statements like (if, for, while, switch) So, I eliminate them adding a case test when finding the match.

`if match not in ('if', 'while', 'for', 'switch'):`

Comment: You can test it on the following link,